# The GRE is not held where I live. How badly does it reflect on me if I ask for it to be waived?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, gre

I am graduating with my MSc early next year and would like to pursue my PhD in a closely related field (Stats/Financial math).

I am hoping to study either in Europe or HK/Singapore and most of the universities I hope to apply to state a GRE is required.

The GRE is not held where I live, and I'm very strapped for cash meaning that I don't really have money to spare to fly to the nearest test center and sit it. I'm wondering how poorly it would reflect on my application if I asked for a test waiver explaining this?

I have already emailed NUS in Singapore asking about this, and they said I was exempted but that it would be better if I did include it. This makes me feel that borrowing some money and doing it would be best, or I'd risk ruining my chances of getting into a good university.

Comment: The GRE is a very US-centric thing. Many european universities do not particularly care about it _provided_ that the rest of your application is strong. I never sat it (and was offered several PhD places).

Comment: In terms of grades, I have straight A/A+ with all A+ in my honours year. And a few scholarships/prizes. Nothing particularly special other than a good GPA. Can I ask where you applied, and went?

Comment: I came from Oxford and went to Oxford, and got offered a place in Germany, Warwick and London along the way, along with a few more ;-). Really, obviously within the caveat of "read the university guidance" and "do what the instructions say", showing that you actually want a research career and _and would be good at it_ is probably far more important. Literally everywhere I applied to was much more interested in the mathematical biology I'd done than my degree mark. Things may vary when it comes to funding, but the only thing applying (should) cost you is your time.

Comment: @Landak you must have applied to Oxford some time ago then; I applied for a PhD there this year and the application fee was £75.

Comment: That's very promising @Landak, thank's for your advice I really appreciate it. Congrats getting into Oxford too, very cool!

Comment: Perhaps they want to be able to plug your numbers into a formula to get a preliminary idea about the merits of your application.  It might be a little bit more work for them to evaluate it without using the formula.  They could have said, "it is strongly encouraged."  But they said something weaker -- "it would be better."

Comment: Suggest explaining what GRE *is*. I have no idea (perhaps because it's a US thing, as noted above).

Comment: Is NUS a university?

Answer (score 3):

It is fine to ask for a waver of admissions requirements.  Just keep in mind that the university may say no.

To increase your chances of success, clearly state why you want to enrol, why you think you are qualified, and why you need a waver.